# Convert the time to the suitable format using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a file whose name is "MCD43A3_Alb_QA_SWIR_2020_061.tif", and I want to split the time "2020_061" and convert to the format "2020-03-01", how can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
def get_image_time(file_single):  
  
    img_time_day_raw = os.path.basename(file_single).split("_")[5]
    img_time_day = img_time_day_raw.split(".")[0]
    img_time_year = os.path.basename(file_single).split("_")[4]
    img_time_str = img_time_year + "03" +img_time_day
    img_time_pd = pandas.to_datetime(img_time_str, format ='%Y/%m/%d)
    return(img_time_pd)
```

Comment: In your code sample you missed a '  in your format, format ='%Y/%m/%d'

Comment: @MarcM, sorry I didnot get what you mean, could you please explain more?

Comment: In your code sample you typed: format ='%Y/%m/%d instead of format ='%Y/%m/%d' . 
A small test on your sample gives me an input for pandas.to_datetime (img_time_str)  = '202003061'.

Comment: Is 061 the day of the year?

Comment: Thanks ,@MarcM. I got what you mean.

Comment: Yes, my question has been solved. But still thanks for your comment. @Zoltan

Answer (score 3):

(Your questions is better suited for stackoverflow.com)

But try using pd.to_datetime and pd.DateOffset:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

filename = r'/home/bera/Downloads/MCD43A3_Alb_QA_SWIR_2020_061.tif'

def fixdate(full_path_and_filename):
    d = os.path.splitext(full_path_and_filename)[0].split('_')[-2:] #['2020', '061']
    d = pd.to_datetime(d[0], format='%Y') + pd.DateOffset(days=int(d[1])-1)
    return d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#fixdate(filename)
#Out[41]: '2020-03-01'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ BERA. It worked well.

Comment: @Hanxi nice. Please accept my answer with the checkbox